# facebook app oauth error (can not be displayed in frame)

Tags: facebook, oauth

I just wanted to create a FB app. I went to developers.facebook.com/apps, set up a new app, created a new folder on my server, copied an old (working) app into the folder, changed the app id, secret, canvas page and canvas url in my configuration file... and it did not work.

It displayed an error: "this content can not be displayed in frame".

I would be grateful if you could help me. Thanks.

I copy here my config file: (I intentionally removed the app id and secret here.)

```
// Facebook App ID/API Key
$appId = '';

// Facebook App Secret
$secret = '';

// Facebook Canvas Page
$redirect_uri = 'https://apps.facebook.com/appname/';

// Facebook Canvas URL
$canvas_url = 'https://myhost.com/appname/';

// Facebook App Permissions
$scope = 'email, publish_actions';

// Configure Facebook connection

require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appId,
  'secret' => $secret,
  'cookie' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    'scope' => $scope,
));

$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
} else {
    header("Location: $loginUrl");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use JavaScript to redirect the user to the login URL using `top.location = '{url}'`, and then use the login redirect url to send them back to your application. Facebook doesn't allow you to use facebook within an iframe, that why you are seeing that error message - pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

> It displays a "this content can not be displayed in frame" errormessage.

And what about this message gives you trouble understanding?

You can't call the auth dialog in an iframe, because it would enable phishing if the user can’t check the sites address.